# Calling Power shell function from .bat file

Tags: powershell

When I try to call below power shell function from .bat file, it's not executing. Here my function needs three parameters. I tried below script from bat file.both of them didn't work. Where have I made a mistake?

```
powershell ".\Deploy.ps1 Install-Application -msi '.\test-1.0.1.msi'
 -InstallPath '.\InstallPath'
 -Environment 'Local'"

powershell NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command  ".\Deploy.ps1 Install-Application -msi '.\test-1.0.1.msi'
 -InstallPath '.\InstallPath'
 -Environment 'Local'"


function Install-Application
{
 param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Msi file should be existing")]
  [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
  [Alias("msi")]
  [string]$File,

  [Parameter(Position=1,HelpMessage="Path wherein the resource file will be installed")]
  [Alias("path")]
  [string]$InstallPath,

  [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Only valid parameters are Local,Dev,Test and Prod")]
  [Alias("env")]
  [ValidateSet("Local","Dev","Prod","Test")]
  [string]$Environment,

  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't wrap it in a function and in your bat just use:

```
powershell.exe -File "c:\pathtoyourfile.ps1" -msi .\test-1.0.1.msi -installpath .\InstallPath -environment Local
```